# Cannot reconcile simple algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

I'm having trouble with a reconciling two statements.

Suppose a merchant has a price he normally charges for goods ($P_{original}$).

Recently he's decided to transition onto Amazon which charges 11.2% of sale, so said merchant must raise his price to compensate exactly for these new fees.  We will call his new price $P_{new}$.

Intuitively, we can look at this as:
$$\begin{align} 
P_{new}=1.112 \times P_{original} \tag{1}
\end{align} 
$$
Conversely, we cant think of this as $P_{original}$ being $11.2\%$ less than $P_{new}$:
$$\begin{align} 
P_{original} = 0.888\times P_{new} \tag{2}
\end{align} 
$$

Substituting (1) into (2) we get:

$$\begin{align}
P_{original} & =0.888 \times (1.112 \cdot P_{original}) \\
&=0.987456 \cdot P_{original}\\ \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Since I am using exact values and no rounding, (3) cannot be true.  $P_{original} \ne 0.987456 \cdot P_{original}$.  So I have a contradiction, despite (1) and (2) being intuitive, straightforward assertions.  Can somebody help me to reconcile this contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you consider $P_{original}=0.888\times P_{new}$. This $0.888$ comes from making $1-0.112$ which is wrong.The $11,2$% must be calculated over the original price not over the new price.

Since $P_{new}=1.112\times P_{original}$ we have that $P_{original}=\frac{1}{0.112}\times P_{new}$

$P_{original}=\frac{1}{0.112}\times P_{new}=\frac{1}{0.112}\times 1.112\times P_{original}=P_{original}$

Answer (score 1):

The value of $P_{\text{new}}$ will have to be such that $(1-11.2\%)P_{\text{new}}=P_{\text{original}}$. In other words,$$P_{\text{new}}=\frac{P_{\text{original}}}{0.888}\approx1.126P_{\text{original}}.$$